# Pass an ID To Twitter Bootstrap Model

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to pass an id to a twitter bootstrap model for a delete confirmation (basic CRUD page) and for the life of me I can't get this working.  Looked at several examples still unable to get to work.  I need to get the data-id to pass to the model and append the href link so that for example they confirm it takes them to the appropiate page (eg: delete.php?id=5)  Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Heres my code:

**The link:**

```
<a href="#msgDelete" data-toggle="modal" class="open-dialog btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">
```

**The Model:**

```
<div id="msgDelete" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-header">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
<h3 id="myModalLabel">Are You Sure?</h3>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<p>Are you sure you want to delete this product?  This action can not be reversed.  <br /><br /><em>Remember if you want to just hide the product from your store you can mark it as inactive.</em></p>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
<a href="delete.php?id=" class="btn btn-danger" id="clink" >Delete Product</a>
</div>
```

**The JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function () {
   var productId = $(this).data('id');
   console.log(productId);
   //$(".modal-body #clink").href( 'delete.php?id=' + productId );
   $("#clink").attr("href", "delete.php?idd=" + productId);
   // As pointed out in comments, 
   // it is superfluous to have to manually call the modal.
   // $('#addBookDialog').modal('show');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look like your code has misprint.

```
$("#clink").attr("href", "delete.php?idd=" + productId);
                                  -----^
```

Should be

```
$("#clink").attr("href", "delete.php?id=" + productId);
```

At least http://jsfiddle.net/egX3W/ shows that you href changes as you want.

Comment: yeah i through that in there to debug, to see of the javascript was even modifying the href at all, the probelm is the ID is never passed

Comment: never passed to the server?

Comment: im trying to pass the id to the model. the delete.php file will interact with the server

Comment: look at my jsfiddle - it`s change href on #clink each time you click on .open-dialog.

Comment: Your jfiddle is working exactly how i want but for some reason i can get to work on my site.  Im getting the following in my console, and idea what is causing that?   

[12:59:05.363] Empty string passed to getElementById(). @ http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js:174

Answer (score 0):

in your code

```
<a href="#msgDelete" data-toggle="modal" class="open-dialog btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">
```

change it to

```
<a data-href="delete.php?id=<?php=productId?>" data-toggle="modal" class="open-dialog btn btn-mini btn-danger" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">
```

so, it will be automatically pass to your javascript... and you won't need to pass it in script...

change your script to this

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-dialog", function () {
 var productId = $(this).data('id');
 console.log(productId);
});
```

Comment: Tried this, the model didnt open, i added back in the href="#msgDelete" so that the model opens but id value is still not passed

Comment: why are you using data-toggle="modal", change it to data-toggle="confirmation" and change the href to data-href again, just like i mentioned before, you won't need href anymore. You want confirmation not modal... http://ethaizone.github.io/Bootstrap-Confirmation/ just try firebug on the "click to toggle confirmation" button